# Windows Vista hangs when network cable is plugged in

Tags: windows-vista, freeze, normal-mode

My sister-in-law has a Dell Inspiron 545MT with Windows Vista Home Premium installed on it. Since this morning, they have the following problem;

1. Booting in Normal Mode with the network cable plugged in: Windows hangs completely after logging in. The desktop (and sometimes a few start-up applications) get loaded, but then everything hangs and I have to do a hard reset.
2. Booting in Normal mode without the network cable plugged in: no problem, *but*, as soon as I plug in the network cable the computer immediately freezes!
3. Booting in Safe Mode: never a problem. Doesn't matter if the network cable is plugged in or not.

What could be the problem here? I have already tried the following;

1. Run Spybot Search & Destroy and Hitman Pro
2. Try turning off a lot of the services set to "Automatic"
3. Reinstall network and motherboard chipset drivers

Answer (score 2):

I do have the same problem. I reinstalled my computers some days ago (Vista). I installed my software and the Windows update service downloaded the updates. The notebook worked for some days without any issues. Then I was copying files to my usb stick. As it took some time I decided to let this run over night. At the morning a saw that Vista didn't respond.

When starting Vista in normal-mode. Everything runs perfect. As soon as I plug in the LAN-cable or activate WLAN it takes 10 sec. and the system stops. I started Wireshark (Network protocol analyser) to see what happens. The network cards sends some packages and the the system stops.

I assume that this isn't a driver problem because a) everything ran perfect before (without changing a driver file) b) in safe-mode it is possible to connect the LAN-cable or enable wireless LAN.

I suspect a windows update for this, but I don't have a evidence.

System: Dell Inspiron 1520
OS: Vista Home Premium SP2
VS: MS Security Essentials

I got the latest network drivers from Dell.
I removed the network drivers and let Vista install them (before the system hung for the first time).

I tried to reset WINSOCK. It did't help.

http://forums.techguy.org/windows-vista/749345-solved-vista-hangs-network-access.html

Greetings from Germany
Alex

Comment: Hi Alex. I have formatted my sister-in-law's computer and reïnstalled Windows Vista. The problem is solved now and I hope it stays that way. Unfortunately, doing a fresh install of Windows actually took less time than all the searching and trying to solve it in another way. Still don't know what caused the problem though.